# phpstorm debugging call stack

Tags: phpstorm

Really quick question about PhpStorm (I see behaviour on version 6 and 7, I'm using XDebug)

When debugging, I can add watches and I can go to different stack frames, but when I try and watch variables in a different stack-frame to the current one that program is in, nothing happens when I try and watch variables (it just goes green and shows no variable value nor error)

[image: nothing on the watch]

My question is, should I be able to watch local variables from other stack frames? (ie has my local configuration got a bug)

And if I can't watch local variables from other stack frames, is there another IDE that will support it?

Comment: I haven't found a solution to this yet. Netbeans supports this feature.

Comment: I don't know if this should work (see watches in non-current frames) but I can confirm it doesn't work for me either.